# Ionic4 OneSignal open push notification redirect page

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

Was hoping to achieve when OneSignal push notification was being opened would redirect to a certain page in the App. Following is my code to redirect to a page called positions but it didn't seem to work. When the push notification is opened, it still opens up the url in the InAppBrowser. Any idea what went wrong? Thanks in advance.

```js
      if (this.appConfig.Onesignal_Enable == true) {
        this.oneSignal.startInit(this.appConfig.OneSignal_AppID, this.appConfig.GCM_SenderID);
        this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
          // do something when notification is received
        });
        this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((data) => {
          // do something when a notification is opened
          // the following two lines pass data I send with the push notification so the app knows what to open
          let pushaction = data.notification.payload.additionalData.action;
          let pushactionvalue = data.notification.payload.additionalData.actionvalue;

          // this fires up the tab-switching
          this.runNotificationAction(pushaction, pushactionvalue);
        });
        this.oneSignal.endInit();
      }

  runNotificationAction(pushaction, pushactionvalue){

    // this is the data passed the the other page
    let data = {"action": pushaction, "value:": pushactionvalue};

 
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('positions');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I'm using v4 ionic too and I achieved this with this implementation on my project:

```
let self = this;
var notificationOpenedCallback = async function(jsonData) {
  //I use info data previous saved, but you can use jsonData
  switch (self.user.role) {
    case "customer":
      self.router.navigate(["history-customer"]);
      break;
    case "provider":
      self.router.navigate(["history-provider"]);
  }
};

window["plugins"].OneSignal.startInit(
  "0*************7",
  "1*********2"
)
  .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
  .endInit();

window["plugins"].OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
```

I use

```
let self = this
```

because startInit receive a callback so is necessary to do that, in your case I don't know if inside subscribe need also use "self" and I use Router to navigate between pages.

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
```

And on my app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'history-provider', loadChildren: './pages/history-provider/history-provider.module#HistoryProviderPageModule' },
{ path: 'history-customer', loadChildren: './pages/history-customer/history-customer.module#HistoryCustomerPageModule' }
```

[image: One signal router]